# Consume web services via LAN

Tags: web-services, iis

I have web services running on my machine on a local network. Instead of connecting to them via `localhost`, I'd like to be able to connect to them via local IP - in this case `192.168.1.5`. Once I can do this, I'll know other devices on the network can consume these web services too (in particular, my android phone).

In my project setup in `Visual Studio 2013` (I am using IIS Express), if I set the project url to be `http://testdomain.com:52252` and set the line in my hosts file for `192.168.1.5 testdomain.com`, then connecting to `testdomain.com:52252/testservices.asmx` works just fine. However when I change the project url to `http://192.168.1.5:52252/` and connect straight to `192.168.1.5:52252/testservices.asmx` it returns `Bad Request - Invalid Hostname. HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.`

What is an effective way of testing web services on a local network? I need to develop and test web services and test them from an android device, but I am disallowed from developing/testing them on a live server at the moment. Are there any solutions to this?

I have looked for solutions online but have been unable to find any. I find it hard to believe there is not a common solution to this issue - surely people must have a way to test web services without hosting a server or connecting via `localhost`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it - I had heard others needing to turn off their firewall in order to get this to work. Personally I was using McAfee to manage my windows firewall - so I'd turned McAfee firewall off assuming that was enough - but I was wrong. Despite turning the firewall off, I still had to go into the advanced windows firewall settings and add an inbound rule to allow all incoming connections over the specified port. It then worked - I could call web services from other devices on the network!

Answer (score 1):

I really see there being two routes to take

1) Route each domain to a vlan with it's own ip

- Virtual LAN - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN
- Configure VLANs in a Microsoft Windows Environment - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19407-01/820-7898-11/z40001c91004554.html

2) Create x number of virtual machines and simulate traffic

Comment: I'm testing this on a physical LAN - I'm not sure how a virtual lan would help. Also virtual machines are not a solution here as I'm trying to specifically test it from multiple computers so I know if it will work from an android device or not.

Comment: you can bounce the connection from one vlan with a set port/ip to a second vlan (all on the host, I should add) that will redirect the connection. Alternatively you could configure your hosts file

Answer (score 0):

The key is to edit the IIS Express file called applicationhost.config.  Add a binding just like localhost, but with your IP address.  Note that you have a binding configuration for each VS2012 project so put it in the one you are using.

Then right click IIS Express in the sytem tray and exit.  Exit VS, then open it using Run As Administrator.  That should do it.

```
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:24486:localhost" />
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:24486:192.168.4.104" />
            </bindings>
```

Comment: I already have my binding information set up like this (which I should have mentioned in the question), but still cannot access these web services over LAN.